# Emgu.CV dont work on windows 7 x64

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have program that works fine in my windows 8 x64. But when i try to run it in my laptop with windows 7 x64 i have some problems.

errors:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: URI formats are not supported.

A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
Additional information: You tried to load the wrong format. (Excluded from the HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Target call threw an exception.

A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Target call threw an exception.

'InzV2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: InzV2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_pl_b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll
Additional information:Calling the constructor for the type of „InzV2.MainWindow” compatible with specific binding constraints caused an exception.

A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Calling the constructor for the type of „InzV2.MainWindow” compatible with specific binding constraints caused an exception., line number 3, position 9.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Calling the constructor for the type of „InzV2.MainWindow” compatible with specific binding constraints caused an exception., line number 3, position 9.
```

This errror looks like this: 
[image]

I'm using Emgu.CV lib from Nuget called: myEmguCV.Net.

even if i try just crete new project with only:

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 pMog11 = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(0, 80, false);
```

i have error..

Comment: I think it worth translating these error messages from Polish to English :) So that more people can understand what's going on

Comment: ok done. i just use google translator but i think this will be good.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when unmanaged assembly is compiled for different platform than your .NET code is currently being compilled to.

For example if the unmanaged dll are in x86 architecture and you are trying to compile your code to x64 .NET runtime, you will get this type of error.

In the image you have provided it seems that you are trying to compile the code to x86 architecture and your EmguCV unmanaged .dlls are probably x64 based.

So go to

Project -> Properties -> Build -> tick the platform that matches the platform for which an unmanaged dll is compiled (x86, x64) (probably in your case it should be x64).

Comment: I have everywhere x84.

Comment: @Misha: Well this only occurs when there is a mismatch against the .NET CLR and the unmanaged dlls.Please check that your Visual studio has 32 bit runtime of .NET

Comment: @Misha Check this link http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_EMGU_C_Sharp